# jQuery onchage not working in IE with file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Here is my sample code I want to upload file via Ajax but in IE it's not working when I click in browser then it's work other wise it not ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#photoimg').live('change', function() {
        // $("#photoimg").bind('propertychange change', function(e) {
        $(this).blur();
        $("#thumbnail").html('');
        $("#thumbnail").html('<img src="assets_admin/images/loader.gif">');
        $("#imageform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#thumbnail'
        }).submit();
        //setTimeout ("empty_image()",10000);
    });
});
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `.on()` instead `live()`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using. Also is "#photoimg" the upload widget?

Comment: What version IE and what does your HTML look like?

Comment: I guess $("#thumbnail").html(''); this code does nothing when your overwriting the content in the next line?

Answer (score 1):

$.live() does not support the change event:

Currently not supported: blur, focus, mouseenter, mouseleave, change, submit http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live

Use delegate instead of live .

```
  $('div.facet_dropdown select').delegate('change', function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, IE, especially IE7/8 doesn't support onchange event very well . I do recommend you use onclick event.

onchange event does not bubble in IE according to MSDN.

Scott Leberknight's on onChange http://www.nofluffjuststuff.com/blog/scott_leberknight/2005/04/onclick_versus_onchange_in_ie_and_firefox